# SaltStack Minion on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: salt-stack, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to install a Salt minion on Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit).

In documentation (http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/windows.html)
I have found that 64 bit version is tested on  Windows 7 64bit and Windows Server 2008R2 64bit.

Has anyone been experiencing any issues with minion on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Note: I posted this question on SaltStack user group, but no answers were provided.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have users on Windows Server 2012 R2. There have been no reported issues that are 2012 R2 specific.

I always recommend testing before pushing to production, though!

Comment: OK, seems it works, but sometimes Salt ping from master fails, and I need to restart the minion. Also, having problem with authentication for executing command on minion. How to set a user on Windows which has privileges to execute Salt?

Comment: How are you executing the command on the minion that's failing? Could you post an example as well as the output you're getting?

Comment: The message is "Failed to authenticate, is this user permitted to execute commands?" and command which I execute (deploy to WebSphere) is: sudo salt -t240 myserver.mydomain state.sls was85win.deploy_wars 'pillar={"BUILDAPPNAME": "my-app", "BUILDJOBWKS": "folder/my_wars", "WAS_USERNAME": "was", "WAS_PASSWORD": "waspassword", "CONTEXTROOT": "myapp"}' -v

Comment: Make sure you're installing 2014.7.1 or the soon to be released 2014.7.2. 2014.7.0 had a memory leak on windows that causes these kinds of problems.